# Erro de consulta utilizando Entity Framework com MySQL e VB.net

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, vb.net

Desenvolvi um metodo para fazer com consulta simples diparado pelo evento Changed de textbox e a consulta retorna os valores certos da primeira vez. Quando mudo o valor do componente e a consulta e solicitada novamente com um novo codigo o resultado é mesmo. Ja tentei de tudo. Alguem pode me ajudar. O código segue abaixo.

Public Shared Function Busca_CQGusaLiq(ID_MatPri As Integer) As ArrayList

```
    Dim ArrLst As ArrayList = New ArrayList

    Dim Q_MatGusLiq As IQueryable(Of TB_MateriaPrima_ThermoLD) = (From p In EF_SSThermoLD.TB_MateriaPrima_ThermoLD 
                                                                  Where p.ID_MatPrima = ID_MatPri
                                                                  Select p)

    Dim CQSelecionada As List(Of TB_MateriaPrima_ThermoLD) = Q_MatGusLiq.ToList()

    If CQSelecionada.Count > 0 Then

        For Each n In CQSelecionada
            ArrLst.Add(n.TeorC)
            ArrLst.Add(n.TeorMn)
            ArrLst.Add(n.TeorSi)
            ArrLst.Add(n.TeorP)
            ArrLst.Add(n.TeorS)
            ArrLst.Add(n.TeorFe)
            Exit For
        Next

    End If

    Return ArrLst

End Function
```